# Django ugettext_lazy with concatenated strings

Tags: python, django, string, concatenation

I have searched for an answer before posting this question. 
There is a bunch of long strings that are split in the following way and need to be translated

```
string = "This is a very long " \
          "string to be translated"
```

after marking

```
string = _("This is a very long " \
          "string to be translated")
```

the resulting .po file keeps only the first part of the string

```
msgid "This is a very long "
msgstr ""
```

So, is there any way to make this work, preferably without messing up the code very much...

Thank you

Comment: I tried the triple quote, which worked, but the thing is the string must not contain \r\n characters (which are added using triple quotes)...

Answer (score 0):

Per the [makemessages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) documentation, when creating messages, use the [--no-wrap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---no-wrap) option.

### My Model

```
class Test(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_(
            'This is a super long description that should never really exist '
            'but it does. Should not wrap.'
        )
    )
```

`./manage.py makemessages --locale=de --no-wrap`

Without `--no-wrap` it looked like this:

```
#: test/models.py:16
msgid ""
"This is a super long description that should never really exist but it does. "
"Should not wrap."
msgstr ""
```

After adding the `--no-wrap` it looks like this:

```
#: test/models.py:16
msgid "This is a super long description that should never really exist but it does. Should not wrap."
msgstr ""
```

Comment: Well actually my problem is that i don't make even the first case to work. Only the first line is extracted.